# Why doesn't D allow overload of nested functions?

Tags: windows, d, dmd

I was using nested functions to break in small pieces part of my code but when I needed to extend a function to support parameters of different types I get a redeclaration compile-error:

> declaration X is already defiend

Is this D's designer (if so, why?) or one of this kind of feature they don't implemented just because is "too few used"?

Code example to reproduce error:

```
void foo()
{
    int baa(int a)
    {
        return a * 2;
    }

    int baa(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and add your code? It's most likely because X is defined in the parental function and you declare it once again in the nested function.

Comment: @L33TS: Added code example.

Comment: Well I assume that it just hasn't been implemented for nested function, it would most likely be implemented sometime, but I don't think anytime soon as it doesn't seem to be an important implementation.

Comment: Doesn't it explicitly say someone in the docs that you can overload nested functions? I could be wrong, and I don't remember where in the docs it says that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find all the details and track progress from
https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12578

> 1. Local functions aren't visible outside of their scope. Their use is pretty limited, and so there isn't much of any benefit to overloadability.
> 2. Forward references aren't allowed in local scope, meaning any use of overloading would be fairly restricted anyway.
>
> It's not impossible to overcome this, it just seems pointless.
>
> -- Walter Bright